# Why my custom vocabulary by default is in Site feature?

Tags: 8, taxonomy-terms, entities, features

I've created custom vocabulary and I want to export it as feature to my existing module.

When I run:

drush fc 25:

> taxonomy_vocabulary:my_vocab  Provided by: site

It's blocking me from exporting this vocab cause:

> No unexported sources match "taxonomy_vocabulary"

any chance to export it to existing module also?

I'm wonder why by default this custom vocabulary goes to Site feature. I think there should be 'Tags' vocab only.